# Trying to get id and value with typeahead.js and php and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete, typeahead.js

I'm trying to get the id and name of countries from database and make an autocomplete which would get the id of the country for further search in db.But when I want to get the name only it works perfectly but when I want to get id as well nothing works anymore. I really appreciate your help.

fetch.php

```
<?php 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
echo 'Connect Error (' . $conn->connect_errno . ') '
    . $conn->connect_error;
}
// $conn;
$request = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["query"]);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM countries where name like '".$request."%' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$data = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 // output data of each row
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $data[] = array('name' => $row["name"] , 'id'=> $row["id"]);
 }
echo json_encode($data);
} 
?>
```

index.php

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('#country').typeahead({
  source: function(query, result)
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"fetch.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{query:query},
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data){
     result($.map(data, function(item){
      return {
          id:item.id,
          name:item.name
      }
     }));
    }
   })
  }
  select: function (event,ui){
     $(this).val(ui.item.name);
     $('#idc').val(ui.item.id);
     return false;
     }
 });
 
});
</script>
```

```html
 <form action="" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="country" id="country" class="form-control input-lg" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type Country Name" />
   <input type="hidden" name="idc" value="" id="idc">
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
     </form>
```

The script above doesn't work because I'm trying to get the id as well.
but the script below works because it just shows name of the country.

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('#country').typeahead({
  source: function(query, result)
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"fetch.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{query:query},
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data){
     result($.map(data, function(item){
      return {
          id:item.id,
          name:item.name
      }
     }));
    }
   })
  }
 });
 
});
</script>
```

Notice that for the script above I just deleted the select:function(event,ui) and nothing else has changed. so I guess that's the problem. because even though I haven't changed the return or anything else it still shows the name.
I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it the same day but i was too busy to update the result here.
my mistake was that i was combining jquery autocomplete and typeahead together.
for what i wanted to do jquery autocomplete was more than enough and here is the code for it

```js
$('#placeautocomplete').autocomplete({
          source: "fetch.php",
          select: function (event,ui){
               $(this).val(ui.item.value)
               $('#placeidautoc').val(ui.item.id);
          },
          minLength: 2,
          autoFocus :true,

     });
```